# What do the IL Prefix OpCodes do?

Tags: .net, il, opcodes

I've been playing around with IL and I noticed OpCodes like [Prefix1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.prefix1%28v=VS.95%29.aspx), with documentation basically telling me not to worry about it.  Naturally, this makes me quite curious as to what these various Prefix OpCodes actually do.  A quick Google search didn't turn up anything, so I thought I'd ask the experts here.  Does anybody know what these mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While most opcodes are a single byte, there are several opcodes in current use that contain 2 bytes.  For example, Opcodes.LdLoc is encoded as 0xfe + 0x0c.  You can probably guess the value of Opcodes.Prefix1, it ix 0xfe.  Prefix2-7 are for future extensibility.  They are marked as "do not use" because multi-byte opcodes already have the prefix included in their value (fields m_s1 and m_s2).

If you're interested in the background info, you'll want to take a look at the [Ecma-335 standard document](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm).

Comment: Cool, thanks.  I'll have to check out the standards document.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/812xyxy2(v=VS.95).aspx

As for the Prefix1, it is a reserved instruction that you should not use. Maybe it is reserved for some future version.

Comment: I appreciate the handy link, but that's actually what I linked to in my question. :)  I'm just excessively curious and hoping someone might have insight into these mysterious instructions.